# WPF and MVVM : How to Refresh controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

It is my first application with WPF, MVVM and Entity framework 6 Code First. It is a simple mini-Credit simulator, composed with left panel that contains parameters of the credit and a datagrid in the right panel that refresh every changes made in parameters, it contains a collection of entity "Echeance". So the left Panel contains Textboxes databinded to Properties in "Simulation" Entity and the datagrid is databinded to ObservableCollection.

The problem is, when i change any parameter, the datagrid doesn't refresh changes.

Before i use MVVM, the application works fine.
Below the code :

```
//Entity Echeance 
 public partial class Echeance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public long echeanceId { get; set; }
    public byte echNumber { get; set; }
    public double principal;
    .... //Other fields
    ...
    //Navigation to the parent

    public virtual simulation simulation { get; set; }


//Contructor with Echeance Number
  Echeance(byte n)
{
echNumber = n;
}

...


   public double MontantPrincipal
    {
        get
        {
            return principal;
        }

        set
        {
            principal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MontantPrincipal");
        }
    }

...Other properties
....
//
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}



//Entity simulation
  public partial class simulation 
{

        public long simulationId { get; set; }
         ...
        public double loyer { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Echeance> echeancier { get; set; }
}
```

The view model is as follows :

```
public class VMSimulation : ObservableObject
{
#region Fields
    simulation _simulation;
     ...        
     ObservableCollection<Echeance> _echeancier;
#endregion


    #region Constructeur
    public VMSimulation()
    {
        _simulation = new simulation();
        _echeancier = new ObservableCollection<Echeance>(_simulation.echeancier);
      //  LogIt();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Echeance> Echeancier
    {
        get
        {
            return _echeancier;
        }

        set
        {
            _echeancier = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Echeancier");
        }
    }

....
  public double Loyer
    {
        get { return _simulation.loyer; }
        set
        {
            _simulation.loyer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Loyer");
        }
    }
...
}
```

XAML Just fields where i have refresh trouble

```
<viblend:NumberEditor x:Name="txloy"    
                                  Value="{Binding Path=Loyer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="2" 
                                  Style="{StaticResource viBlendDecimal}" Width="72"  ToolTip="Loyer computed." IsEnabled="False"  />


<DataGrid x:Name="gridLoyers" ItemsSource="{Binding Echeancier}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                   Margin="0"
              Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" CellEditEnding="gridLoyers_CellEditEnding_1"   >
               <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NumLoy, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:#}'}"   ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"        Header="N°" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateEcheance ,       StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}, Mode=TwoWay}"     ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellCenterAlignment}"    Header="Echéance"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MontantPrincipal,  StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}',UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"      ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"  Header="Principal" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MontantInteret, StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}'}"     ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"  Header="Intérêts"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MontantHT, StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"    Header="Hors taxe"  />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MontantTVA, StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}'}"       ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"    Header="TVA"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MontantTTC, StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}'}"      ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"     Header="TTC"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Amortfin, StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}'}"        ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"     Header="Amortissement"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Encours, StringFormat='{}{0:#.##,0}'}"         ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"     Header="Encours financier"/>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Fixe, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"         ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellRightAlignment}"     Header="Figé ?"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

and finally The view :

```
  //Constructeur de la fenêtre
    public simulationform()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VMSimulation vms = new VMSimulation();  //Instanciation du ViewModel Associé
        this.DataContext = vms;
        vms.ClosingRequest += (sender, e) => this.Close();
    }
```

datagrid doesn't refresh ObservableCollection and "Loyer" property is not refreshed. I debug this and i find that "Command"  works fine and List contains correct data but it is not refreshed.
When i click on any column header , data in datagrid will be refreshed  correctly. Strange Behavior !!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a UI control to update changes made in a view model, the view model *and* the data object class must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. It looks like you have done this, but I can't be sure that your implementation works.

Comment: Try `ItemsSource="{Binding Echeancier, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried it...still same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me, the code of the command in ViewModel is missing.

```
public ICommand RefreshCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_refreshCommand == null)
                _refreshCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(RefreshCommandExecute);
            return _refreshCommand;
        }
    }



void RefreshCommandExecute(object obj)
    {
        _simulation.RefreshEcheancier();
        //I added this line and it works fine
        Echeancier = new ObservableCollection<Echeance>(_simulation.echeancier);
    }
```

So I recently added the line :

```
Echeancier = new ObservableCollection<Echeance>(_simulation.echeancier);
```

and datagrid refresh works fine.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

By setting the value to the field you by-pass your property setter along with the INotifyPropertyChange trigger, so in the ctor do set your value to the property not the field.

Codewise if the constructor of your VM:

```
    #region Constructeur
    public VMSimulation()
    {
        _simulation = new simulation();
        Echeancier = new ObservableCollection<Echeance>(_simulation.echeancier); // instead of _echeancier = ...
      //  LogIt();
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: can you clarify a little please ? Do you mean i have to inherit simulation from INotifyPropertyChanged yet ?

Comment: by setting value to the filed you're bypassing Echeancier property setter, thus OnPropertyChanged("Echeancier"); is never called and VM doesn't get a chance to report about the change.

Comment: user3455395 : i wrote it correct. Please review my code above. I wrote :  _echeancier = new ObservableCollection<Echeance>(_simulation.echeancier); Not  Echeancier = new ObservableCollection<Echeance>(_simulation.echeancier);

Comment: You'll need to set the property in order for the binding to work. Just try updating your constructor to use property and see if it'll work.